# Dealing with nested/complex objects in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Is there someone familiar with Vuex and Vue.js that could help me with some code?

Either by handing me advice, or point me towards some similar situation to solve my problem.

I have a comment section (module: comments) representing an array of comment object.
Each comment have a '`tags section', 'replies section`', needing to be reactive on mutations and to store mutations in db.

- Option 1: having only one module: comments containing actions for all entities (`comments, tags, replies`) - would fill comments module with unrepresentative actions
- Option 2: having '`replies, tags`' and asociated actions living as vue data of components '`replies section' and 'tags section'`
- Option 3: described here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/2 , but I don't know if I need  to have a module for each entity (`comments, replies, tags`)

with mention of that my API returns nested object:

```
`comments:[
  {
    id,
    title,
    text,
    replies: [{
      id,
      author: {id, name}
      comment_id,
      text
    }],
    tags: [similar with replies]
  },
//
]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of relational/nested data, I'd suggest trying [vuex-orm](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/). It allows you to normalize your data schema within Vuex Store with relationships, as you would represent it in regular DB. It also has a lot of integrations with `axios`, `GraphQL`, etc.

Comment: I started using this. Is a lot to learn, adding more complexity to my code. I implement my own vuex-orm-axios plugin with posibility of callback after actions. Is nicer syntax, it equalise frontend and backend code. Now I have something like Comment.$fetch().onSuccess(extra actions using response)